# backticks do not return any value in perl

Tags: perl

I wrote a perl script in Cygwin environment. Inside, I use backticks to execute another program, and returned value is assigned to a variable. It worked fine before I upgraded some packages in cygwin two weeks ago. Now the backticks do not return any value. Any thoughts?

Comment: The obvious question is "what happens when you execute the program from the command line manually?"  Does it still work?

Comment: Can you put the actual command with backticks, or some facsimile thereof, in the question?  There's very little to go on here.

Comment: `command1.exe file1 file2 cutoff1` command1.exe is a command that I worte in VB. it read file1 file2, then do some calculation and output resulsts that pass cutoff1.  system ("command1.exe file1 file2 cutoff1") works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try checking the value of $?.  It contains the return code of the last external command executed, but it's overloaded to contain extra information, such as the signal that killed the command and whether there was a core dump, etc.

The actual return code can be obtained through

```
my $return_code = $? >> 8;
```

If it's zero, the command executed successfully, if not, that's the error status the commadn exited with (what int main() returns with in C, for example).