# How to determine if shell command didn't run or produced no output

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I am executing some shell commands via a perl script and capturing output, like this,

```
$commandOutput = `cat /path/to/file | grep "some text"`;
```

I also check if the command ran successfully or not like this,

```
if(!$commandOutput)
{
    # command not run!
}
else
{
    # further processing
}
```

This usually works and I get the output correctly. The problem is, in some cases, the command itself does not produce any output. For instance, sometimes the text I am trying to `grep` will not be present in the target file, so no output will be provided as a result. In this case, my script detects this as "command not run", while its not true.

What is the correct way to differentiate between these 2 cases in perl?

Comment: you should not be using perl to execute cat and grep. perl can do it just as easy, faster, and more secure

Comment: Indeed, but there are many others for which perl has no alternatives, so I just built a general system to run commands and grab output, which will be processed by perl.

Comment: @Sibster: grep easily beats Perl in a speed race. Possibly by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: @Adrian, but calling starting a shell to execute grep is slow, so I guess it would depend on the number of files and the size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this to know whether the command failed or the command return nothing

```
$val = `cat text.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*'`;    
print "command failed" if (!$?);    
print "empty string" if(! length($val) );    
print "val = $val";
```

assume that text.txt contain "123ab" from which you want to get number only.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$?` to check if the command executed successfully: see [backticks do not return any value in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303590/backticks-do-not-return-any-value-in-perl) for an example.

Comment: Since I've used piping to include grep in my command, $? will return the result of `grep` right ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not piping to `|grep` you can check `$?` for more specific exit status,

```
my $commandOutput = `grep "some text" /path/to/file`;

if ($? < 0)
{
    # command not run!
}
elsif ($? >> 8 > 1)
{
   # file not found
}
else
{
    # further processing
}
```